# How to import a list of different XML elements as a single field with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

Let's say the XML is:

```
<person>
  <friends>
    <human id="11"/>
    <human id="24"/>
    <dog id="31"/>
  </friends>
</person>
```

And I want the result to be:

```
class Person {
  public List<Friend> friends;
}

class Friend {
  public int id;
}
```

Preferably the Friend class would also have a "type" field with "human|dog" but I can live without it.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that the XML list is ordered and if it's imported as separate lists of humans and dogs the ordering is partially lost.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the option, it is best to change your XML structure to match your object model.

```
<person>
  <friends>
    <friend type="human" id="11"/>
    <friend type="human" id="24"/>
    <friend type="dog" id="31"/>
  </friends>
</person>
```

Otherwise, your best bet is to parse your XML into a free-format DOM using JAXP, and then trace it to create your POJO model.

JAXP Tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html